# how to diagnose a memory-related Java crash on production linux box

Tags: java, linux

In production we have a CentOS 5 linux box running multiple instances of Apache Tomcat 5.5.30 over Java 1.6.0_21.  Each Tomcat is hosting a Java EE WebApp  which pulls data from a Postgres 9.1 RDBMS and generates HTML/PDF/etc reports.
Every few days, due to triggers that have yet to be determined, one of the Java processes will start ramping up it's RAM usage (to dozens of gigs) until the machine starts to page memory to HD, bringing the entire server to a stand-still.
I would usually use JProbe to monitor what Objects are consuming all the RAM, but since the server is a headless linux installation, that's not an option.
Is there a headless (CLI) tool that will log which Java objects are consuming the most memory at regular intervals?  Is that even the best way to go about diagnosing the issue?

**UPDATE:**
Using the feedback received below, I realised that part of the problem is that we're not getting an actual crash, but the processes just page RAM onto the HD until the whole machine becomes unresponsive.  One solution to this (i thought) would be to set the -Xmx parameter to limit the maximum RAM Java can use to a couple of GB.  Unfortunately, it seems as though the JVM is ignoring this setting, and consuming as much as it wants without crashing.  Is there another way to enforce a limit?

Comment: Can you pls tell JVM and OS version.

Comment: Also, please do a ps -el | grep java and post the final parameters being passed to the process.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here:

1. Your VM will not page unless the available RAM < Max Heap defined. So, please esnure that Max heap defined is less than available RAM (Total RAM - RAM used by all other processes)
2. Next, assuming you are seeing OutOfMemoryErrors, plesae enable heap dump on OOME by adding the JVM parameter -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
3. When you get the problem next time, you will have a heap dump, that can be analyzed using Eclpise MAT or Yourkit profiler to see what is filling up the memory. That will tell you which part of code is actually causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about that.

Obviously the first step would be to enable garbage collection logging (add params like -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/path/to/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails etc)

Next in line are the JDK tool (jvisualvm with the visuagc plugin) and jmap (jmap -histo gives you a run down on live objects) .. yes, jvisualvm is a GUI tool, but I assume you can do X fowarding.

Don't mind to fiddle a bit yourself? Why not write BTrace probes for your key classes and methods?

Still not enough information? May want to try tools like AppDynamicsLite (free spin-off off a commercial too .. http://www.appdynamics.com/products-free-download.php )

That's kind of the toolkit that I'd bring for the job.

Comment: You can use [GCViewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html) to help analyze the GC logs. The site also has some other tips on how to work through memory problems.